# Extract list-elements

Tags: r

I have a list where all vectors have the same length, for example

```
tmp<-list(1:10, -5:5, 3:13)
names(tmp)<-c("a","b","c")
```

I would like to extract the elemenets of `tmp` where `tmp$a == 1`, i.e., the desired output should be equivalent to

```
output<-list(1,-5,3)
names(output)<-c("a","b","c")
```

Inspired by MATLAB I tried with `tmp[tmp[["a"]] == 1, ]`, but that produced an error. Why is that and what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on the specific requirements here, but maybe `sapply(tmp,"[[",1)` or `sapply(tmp,"[[",which(tmp$a == 1))`?

Comment: @BillyJean your approach fails because you are trying to treat `tmp` as a two-dimensional matrix, which it isn't. (Tip: if you say something "produced an error", please give the code and the error - it helps us).

Comment: @joran you probably want to wrap that in `as.list` to get exactly the output requested. Or use `lapply`.

Comment: @Spacedman Or I should have just used `lapply` instead of `sapply` in the first place, probably, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems you are basically describing a data.frame without using one. First, your example does not have equal length vectors, but this does:

```
tmp <- list(a=1:11, b=-5:5, c=3:13)
```

If we convert this to a data.frame, we can use `subset()`

```
subset(data.frame(tmp), a==1)
#   a  b c
# 1 1 -5 3
```

data.frames are basically just lists were all elements are vectors of equal length.

Otherwise @joran's answer still stands. You can apply the indexing operator over each vector in the list

```
lapply(tmp, "[[", which(tmp$a == 1))
```